# Import helper package unavailable (Python)

Tags: import, helper, sha256, bitcoin

Import helper package unavailable (Python)

I am trying to import helper package on Python with module hash256

However it's not working

```py
from ecc import S256Point, G, N
from helper import hash256
e = int.from_bytes(hash256(b'my secret'), 'big')
z = int.from_bytes(hash256(b'my message'), 'big')
k = 1234567890
r = (k*G).x.num
k_inv = pow(k, N-2, N)
s=(z+r*e)*k_inv%N
point = e*G

print(point) # S256Point(028d003eab2e428d11983f3e97c3fa0addf3b42740df0d211795ffb3be2f6c52, \ 0ae987b9ec6ea159c78cb2a937ed89096fb218d9e7594f02b547526d8cd309e2)
print(hex(z)) # 0x231c6f3d980a6b0fb7152f85cee7eb52bf92433d9919b9c5218cb08e79cce78
print(hex(r)) # 0x2b698a0f0a4041b77e63488ad48c23e8e8838dd1fb7520408b121697b782ef22
print(hex(s)) # 0xbb14e602ef9e3f872e25fad328466b34e6734b7a0fcd58b1eb635447ffae8cb9
```

Or do you have an idea to do a double sha256 (it is hash256)?

I tried this:

```py
from hashlib import sha256 as h

print(h(h("my secret".encode()).hexdigest().encode()).hexdigest())
```

It's almost working however the result does not match as it is not starting with 0x.